# Selecting multiple max timestamps from database

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a table with multiple products. For each product, I am collecting an history of prices. Thus I have four columns:

- log_entry
- product_id
- product_price
- timestamp

Until now, I updated all prices at the same time. This lead to an easy query: In a subquery, I filtered the max timestamp and then got all prices and products.

Today I changed my update policy: I now update prices for products asynchronously. This means, when I use my old query, I only get a product-price-pair with the maximum timestamp.

How do I get the most current price/the maximum timestamp for every product in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use group by on a result that was sorted by timestamp. Not sure if it works:

```
select * from (
  select * from products 
    order by timestamp desc
) as products_temp
group by product_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the timestamp field is of `timestamp` data type, then on every field update of a record, this timestamp field can get updated automatically. For that to happen your ts field should have been defined like in the following table pseudo example.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  product ...
  price ...
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

And when you update only other fields like product, or price, ts fields get updated with current timestamp. Then your old query should be returning the latest updated records too.